# What rotation should I apply to my hamburger?

Tags: css

I'm trying to animate a simple two-line span which transforms into an 'X' shape when you click on it - but can't for the life of me work out what rotation I should do to align them properly. They just aren't rotating/translating to be a perfect 'X' shape.

```js
// Variables

let line1 = document.getElementById("line-1");
let line2 = document.getElementById("line-2");
let hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger-container");

// Function

function active() {
  line1.classList.toggle("active");
  line2.classList.toggle("active");
}


// Event Listener

hamburger.addEventListener("click", active);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-section {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #999;
}

#hamburger-container {
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 10%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger-line {
  height: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}


#line-1.active {
  transform: translate(10px, 10px) rotate(-45deg);
}

#line-2.active {
  transform: translate(10px, -10px) rotate(45deg)
}
```

```html
<header class="header-section">
    <div id="hamburger-container">
      <span id="line-1" class="hamburger-line"></span>
      <span id="line-2" class="hamburger-line"></span>
    </div>
  </header>
```

If anybody can explain how they'd work it out too, that'd be great. I can't find the right resource out there for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `space-between` instead of `space-around` and reduce the height to `20px`. Now the space bettwen the bars is exactly `10px` and each bar is `5px` height so you have to move by `7.5px (10px/2 + 5px/2)` vertically:

```js
// Variables

let line1 = document.getElementById("line-1");
let line2 = document.getElementById("line-2");
let hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger-container");

// Function

function active() {
  line1.classList.toggle("active");
  line2.classList.toggle("active");
}


// Event Listener

hamburger.addEventListener("click", active);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-section {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #999;
}

#hamburger-container {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 10%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger-line {
  height: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#line-1.active {
  transform: translateY(7.5px) rotate(-45deg);
}

#line-2.active {
  transform: translateY(-7.5px) rotate(45deg)
}
```

```html
<header class="header-section">
  <div id="hamburger-container">
    <span id="line-1" class="hamburger-line"></span>
    <span id="line-2" class="hamburger-line"></span>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks - that works. Appreciate the explanation too - makes sense with the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CSS rule for `#hamburger-container.active` which changes the containers height to 40px in order to change the vertical distance between the lines to fit the 45°  angle between them, and add a line to the `active()` function to toggle that class.

```js
// Variables

let line1 = document.getElementById("line-1");
let line2 = document.getElementById("line-2");
let hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger-container");

// Function

function active() {
  line1.classList.toggle("active");
  line2.classList.toggle("active");
  hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
}


// Event Listener

hamburger.addEventListener("click", active);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-section {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #999;
}

#hamburger-container {
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 10%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger-line {
  height: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}


#line-1.active {
  transform: translate(10px, 10px) rotate(-45deg);
}

#line-2.active {
  transform: translate(10px, -10px) rotate(45deg)
}
#hamburger-container.active {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-section">
    <div id="hamburger-container">
      <span id="line-1" class="hamburger-line"></span>
      <span id="line-2" class="hamburger-line"></span>
    </div>
  </header>
```